# How to get unique identifier in iphone

Tags: ios, uuid

I want to fetch the device unique id and store in to webservice. i have use

```
[[[UIDevice currentDevice] identifierForVendor] UUIDString];
```

this code for getting uuid but my problem is that when i delete the application and install it again it give me the different uuid value. how to solve. please help me.

Comment: Apple not only discourages you but won't allow you to get a unique identifier for a device/user...

Comment: Save it in NSUserDefaults

Comment: @Arbitur if you delete the application then associated user defaults also would be deleted.

Answer (score 2):

You should use the Advertising Identifier if you target iOS 6 and above, **and if you present ads in your app** (see the edit below) :

```
NSString *adId = [[[ASIdentifierManager sharedManager] advertisingIdentifier] UUIDString];
```

You have to include `AdSupport.framework`.

The advertising identifier will only be reset if the system is reset, or if the user manually resets the identifier in the device settings.

Here is [an article about Unique Identifiers](http://www.doubleencore.com/2013/04/unique-identifiers/) (dating from before iOS 7, but still pretty nice), and here is the recapitulative table of available identifiers they made :

[image: Identifiers]

---

**Edit :**

As @Volker commented, **Apple is now rejecting apps using the advertising identifier if they don't present ads**. If your app doesn't present ads, have a look at the table and choose another identifier. If you do present ads, you should be good to go.

Comment: Apple seems to have shut down this possibility. It will only work if you actually also show ads.

Comment: @Volker : Reading your comment reminded me that I indeed saw that they started rejecting apps using the advertising identifier if they do not show ads. Do you have any official / reliable link ?

Comment: If you need the identifier to survive app reinstall, I think you are in one way breaking a contract with your user. Upon uninstall, the user expects all app data to be wiped clean.

Comment: While not official, they show screenshots of the app store submission re IDFA http://techcrunch.com/2014/04/11/apple-developers-must-now-agree-to-ad-identifier-rules-or-risk-app-store-rejection/